# Comparing ACF date with today's date

Tags: wordpress, compare, advanced-custom-fields

on page http://andilek.laceup.cz/komunita/ I'm trying to separate future trips from past ones by comparing ACF date with today's date. But today's date in comparing always seems higher.

```
$today = date("m/d/Y");                 
$todayj = strtotime($today); 

$pdate = get_field('datum', false, false);
$pdate = new DateTime($pdate);              
$pdatex = $pdate->format('m/d/Y');

if ($pdatex > $todayj) {
```

Thanks for help,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = strtotime("2019-01-20"); // input
$date2 = strtotime("today"); //today date
if($date1 < $date2) {
   echo " input date is in the past";
}
```

Try this way

Comment: I've tried a lot of way to do this but I'm not able.. Is there a required setup like YYYY-MM-DD or whatever? I'm storing on ACF like DD.MM.YYYY